# Setting a NamingStrategy for querydsl-maven-plugin

Tags: java, mysql, maven, querydsl

I'm using `querydsl-maven-plugin` to generate entities and beans for a bunch of MySQL tables in Maven.

Is there a way to tell the plugin to generate with, say, `OriginalNamingStrategy` instead of `DefaultNamingStrategy`?

The current comments seem to show that there are only the following options. I couldn't seem to find anything in the source to set a `NamingStrategy` but would much appreciate it if this were possible.

```
<!--
    optional elements :      
    * jdbcUser = connection user
    * jdbcPassword = connection password
    * namePrefix = name prefix for generated query classes (default: Q)
    * schemaPattern = ant style pattern to restrict code generation to certain schemas (default: null)
    * tableNamePattern = ant style pattern to restrict code generation to certain tables (default: null)
    * exportBeans = set to true to generate beans as well, see section 2.14.13 (default: false)
    * innerClassesForKeys = set to true to generate inner classes for keys (default: false)
    * validationAnnotations = set to false to disable serialization of validation annotations (default: true)
-->
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking out this code, I realized that you can just set the `namingStrategyClass` property (it is not documented.)

https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/blob/master/querydsl-maven-plugin/src/main/java/com/mysema/query/maven/AbstractMetaDataExportMojo.java

Comment: Google is linking to outdated documentation. QueryDSL 3.6.0's documentation includes this parameter: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.0/reference/html/ch02s03.html#d0e654